# Get Average of Numbers

Tags: java

I am supposed to calculate the sum of three double numbers and get its average.
I am required to use the following two methods, no changing them:
`getNumbers()` which only gets the user inputs, no argument, no return. `getAverage()` which calculate the average of the three double numbers, returns the average, and has no argument.

My question is every time I run it on CMD, it shows that method does not work and will not print an output. For me to enter three numbers, and get its average at the end.

If someone can give me advice as to what I am doing wrong, it will be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ComputeAverage{
    double firstNum;
    double secondNum;
    double thirdNum; 
    double sum;
    double average;

    public void getNumbers(){
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your first number: ");
        double firstNum = keyboard.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter your second number: ");
        double secondNum = keyboard.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter your third number: ");
        double thirdNum = keyboard.nextDouble();
        Test.println("The average is: " + average);
    }
    public double getAverage(double firstNum, double secondNum, double thirdNum){
        double average = firstNum + secondNum + thirdNum / 3; 
        return average;  

    }
}
```

Comment: You should learn Operator precedence https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues in your code. First of all, it will not compile as `Test` is an unknown. You have also declared `firstNum`, `secondNum` and `thirdNum` as member variables, but they are also declared as local variables in `getNumbers()`. You have to decide to use member variables, or pass the values as arguments to `getAverage()`.

The next thing is that `/` has precedence over `+`, so `thirdNum / 3` will be calculated first.

It's not necessary, but I think it is better to type `/ 3.0` as the `3` will be converted to double anyway, just to be as clear as possible.

It could for example look like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ComputeAverage{
    double firstNum;
    double secondNum;
    double thirdNum;

    public void getNumbers(){
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your first number: ");
        firstNum = keyboard.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter your second number: ");
        secondNum = keyboard.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter your third number: ");
        thirdNum = keyboard.nextDouble();
    }
    public double getAverage(){
        return (firstNum + secondNum + thirdNum) / 3.0;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ComputeAverage ca = new ComputeAverage();
        ca.getNumbers();
        System.out.println("The average is: " + ca.getAverage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

While you should learn the [operator precedence for Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html), this comes from [BOMDAS](http://www.skillsyouneed.com/num/bodmas.html) which applies to [maths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics).

The `/` operator has higher precedence than `+` which means what you have is

```
double average = firstNum + secondNum + (thirdNum / 3);
```

most likely what you intended was

```
 double average = (firstNum + secondNum + thirdNum) / 3;
```

Also I suspect you wanted to call this method as well.

```
 Test.println("The average is: " + getAverage(firstNum, secondNum, thirdNum);
```

I would also turn all your fields into local variables to avoid confusion. Note: Your IDE should hint to you to do this and give you an auto-fix.

Answer (score 0):

In here you don't have a main method which is the programe's entry point. And you have initialized 3 local variables inside getNumber() which is not visible to getAverage()

```
import java.util.Scanner;
    public class ComputeAverage{
        double firstNum;
        double secondNum;
        double thirdNum; 
        double sum;
        double average;

        public void getNumbers(){
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter your first number: ");
            this.firstNum = keyboard.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Enter your second number: ");
           this.secondNum = keyboard.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Enter your third number: ");
            this.thirdNum = keyboard.nextDouble();

        }
        public double getAverage(double firstNum, double secondNum, double thirdNum){
            double average = (firstNum + secondNum + thirdNum )/ 3; 
            return average;  

        }

    public static void main (String [] arg){

    getNumbers();

    getAverage( firstNum, secondNum, thirdNum);

      Test.println("The average is: " + average);
    }
    }
```

Comment: I think you need to learn about operator precedence, and variable scopes.

Comment: Or BOMDAS from Maths. ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey, yes :-)

Answer (score 0):

3 thing you need to consider in order to make this code to work

1. need to call the `System.out.println`, or define a static method println in a class Test (you didnt post it, so I guess you dont have it)
2. average value is not going to update is value automatically, you need to call the method you defined... `getAverage`
3. dont forget the operator precedence in the  `getAverage`

---

summarizing, you need to:

replace this:

```
Test.println("The average is: " + average);
```

with

```
System.out.println("The average is: " + getAverage(firstNum, econdNum,  thirdNum));
```

and because of the operator precedence do this:

```
public double getAverage(double firstNum, double secondNum, double thirdNum){
        double average = (firstNum + secondNum + thirdNum) / 3; 
        return average;  

    }
```